# Minimum number of colors that are needed to color the vertices of a K5 graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have found this question on internet, Anyone have idea how to solve this?

What is the minimum number of colors that are needed to color the vertices of a K5 graph such that no adjacent vertices have the same color? Why?

Comment: I think the chromatic number of K5 is five. it does not contradict the four-color-theorem since k5 is non-planar, the theorem does apply to k5... is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

In a complete graph, with $n$ vertices, you always need to use $n$ colors. Suppose, that $K_n$ can be colored with $n-1$ colors. Then there are $2$ vertices with the same color, which, from definition are neighbours, and this results in contradiction. $\rightarrow χ(K_n) \ge n$.

In a graph with $n$ vertices, $χ$ will always be at maximum the number of vertices. $χ(K_n) \le n$.

$\rightarrow χ(K_n) = n$.

Comment: think the chromatic number of K5 is five. it does not contradict the four-color-theorem since k5 is non-planar, the theorem does apply to k5... is it correct?

Comment: $K5$ is not planar, just look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem I think it is easier to just think it through instead trying to apply 4-color-theorem. The answer I gave you works for every $n$, for your case $n=5$, therefore the answer is indeed $5$.

Comment: That's what is said K5 is non planer. so the minimum colors would be 5? right?

Comment: Yes, that works too.